# What is meant by re-absorption?

Tags: human-biology, kidney

It is said that PCT, DCT, Henle’s Loop reabsorb the filtrate. Does that mean they absorb the filtrate again? If it is actually reabsorbed to medulla then why it is said that PCT, DCT or Henle’s loop reabsorb the filtrate?

Answer (score 1):

In the glomerulus of the nephron we have filtration occuring. The subsequent formation of an ultra-filtrate travels down the tubulus from Bowmans space; during this journey, the filtrate will be exposed to various transporters and forces such as solvent drags and diffusion gradients, which leads to the (*re*)absorption of this filtrate. Reabsorption occurs also in medullary tubules and later collecting ducts, until the filtrate (by now urine) reaches the calyces. (Note that secretion - that tubular cells permit the transportation of various electrolytes for instance to the tubulary lumen - also occurs in the nephron, giving it three ways to manipulate the its luminal contents: filtration, reabsorption and secretion)